# Orchard CMS: Resources getting a 404 (Not Found)

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating a theme for Orchard CMS 1.10. I'm using a Bootstrap template as a basis. There are quite a number of CSS and JavaScript files that I'm including. All of them however are not being found.

I created a ResourceManifest class to define them:

```
manifest.DefineScript("ThemejQuery").SetUrl("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery-1.11.3.min.js");
manifest.DefineScript("Bootstrap").SetUrl("~/Scripts/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js").SetDependencies("ThemejQuery");
manifest.DefineScript("jQueryScrollTo").SetUrl("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery-scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js").SetDependencies("ThemejQuery");
manifest.DefineScript("BackToTop").SetUrl("~/Scripts/plugins/back-to-top.js").SetDependencies("ThemejQuery");
```

and am calling them so in my Document.cshtml:

```
Script.Require("jQuery").AtFoot();
Script.Require("Bootstrap").AtFoot();
Script.Require("jQueryScrollTo").AtFoot();
Script.Require("BackToTop").AtFoot();
```

In each directory that these css and js files reside, I'm including a web.config file to allow access:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer]

the web.config files all look like:

[image]

and yet none of these files are being served. I don't believe that the paths are an issue, e.g. using '~/Scripts'. The paths are correct (as far as I can see):

[image]

I've googled the hell out of this but cannot find a solution. I've tried running this within IIS Express in Visual Studio as well as full-blown IIS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the '~/Scripts', the resource manager looks for scripts in the modules 'Script' folder and for styles in the 'Styles' folder.

Comment: I'll take a look at that, but I don't think that's the issue. I updated my question to include a screenshot of the failing paths. The paths LOOK right. I'm thinking it's a permissions issue, i.e. web.config. But I've done the web.config bit.

Comment: No, the paths aren't correct. By default they should point to the modules path ie http://wedding.local/yourmodule/scripts/...

Comment: Have a look in any of the core modules ResourceManagers for comparison. Or here http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-7

Comment: Other than that your Styles and Scripts need the default web.configs.

Comment: Does that mean that you have to dump all your files by themselves into these directories (styles, scripts, etc)? Or can you have have some hierarchy in there? For example, I'm using the Bootstrap Image Gallery plugin. It uses javascript, css, and images. How do those get split up?

Comment: You can save the structure, but place css in `Styles`, js in `Scripts` and images in `Content`. You will then need to modify you js/css files to fix the files references

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the addHandler of your web.config (inside Scripts or Styles) addHandler like:

```
<add name="StaticFileHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
```

Comment: Indeed, in my case Scripts folder was missed web.config file. And it solves the problem.